# Creating contract from another contract - remix issue

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

UPDATE: This works fine on the testnet/mainnet.  For some reason the JavascriptVM in remix doesn't like it.  If anyone from remix sees this and could lend a hand though!

I wrote some a contract factory code and I'm trying to test it out in the remix browser.  I keep getting an invalid opcode error when I run the createContract bit.

```
contract test{

    function test(address OAddress, bytes32 _name,address _cpty1, address _creator) {

    }

}


contract Factory {
    address[] public newContracts;
    address public creator;
    address public ID;
    bytes32 public Name;
    modifier onlyOwner{require(msg.sender == creator); _;}
    event Print(address _name, address _value);

    function Factory (bytes32 _Name, address _ID){
        creator = msg.sender;  
        Name = _Name;
        ID = _ID;
    }

    function createContract () payable returns (address){
        address newContract = new test(ID,Name,msg.sender,creator);
        newContracts.push(newContract);
        Print(msg.sender,newContract);
        return newContract;
    } 
    function withdrawFee() onlyOwner {
        creator.transfer(this.balance);
    }
}
```

It was working last week, but for some reason I get this error now.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem on the test net again. I have trouble creating new contracts as well. Although they publish on Ropsten (I can see via EtherScan), browser solidity doesn't recognizes them and Metamask gives an contract pubished failed error.